# Pulling data from a range

Tags: retrying

Looking for the script or formula to pull data from a range of houses on a separate sheet, based on the available sized home that can be built.

Heres the initial process. We are calculating

1. "Size of the block (m2)" eg.350m2
2. "R Code" (which determines the minimum percentage of the land has to be filled by the house to fit in that location. eg R20 (50%min)
3. We get the "Min house size (m2)" of eg. 175m2

Once we have this data we can then go through the list to tell a client what house design can be built on their block.

But there is one more variable which is the "Frontage" eg. 7.5 (meters)

See the range below for more detail.

```
Size of block   R Code  Min house size (m2) Frontage (m)
350         20  175             8

= 
Name            House size (m2) Frontage (m)
Verona          101.6           7.5
Oakland         107.5           7.5
Santa Fe        135.5           7.5
Mornington      147.3           7.5
Newport         152         7.5
Seattle         170.4           7.5
Montreal        173.1           7.5
```

I want the land size filtered to only show the ones available

Hope this makes sense

```
House Design Table


Name            House size (m2) Frontage (m)
Verona          101.6           7.5
Oakland         107.5           7.5
Santa Fe        135.5           7.5
Mornington      147.3           7.5
Newport         152         7.5
Langley         166.7           10
Seattle         170.4           7.5
Como            170.6           12.5
Dianella        170.7           14
Sanctuary       172.3           10
Montreal        173.1           7.5
Berkley     176         7.5
Davenport   176.8           8.5
Montana         178.4           8.5
Retreat         179.3           15
Colorado    184.8           10
Piara           187.7           12.5
Valencia    189.9           15
Kingston    190         15
Paradise    190.8           10
Esperance   190.8           10
Boston          190.8           10
Brooklyn    192.4           10
Florence    192.8           15
Lisbon          195.1           12.5
Santorini   201.3           10
Cambridge   204.4           15 
Wembley         207.1           12
Bussleton   207.1           12 
Noosa           211.7           12
Monte Carlo 212.8           12
Serenity    212.9           12
Milan           212.9           12
Oxford          224.4           12
Bondi           225         12
Vienna          226.9           12
Glades          230.6           12.5
Fusion          236.1           12.5
Chantilly   238.6           12.5
Sorrento    243.8           15
Sienna          244.2           15
Tranquility 244.5           15
Venice          244.5           15
Urban           258.2           15
Lawley          259.7           15
Dunsborough 259.7           15
Brunswick   259.7           15
Duo         261.4           15
Byron           265.2           15
California  266.5           15
Montego Bay 273.4           15
Prevelly    278.2           15
Dallas          288.1           17
Vancouver   289.5           15.65
Manhattan   315.9           17
Supreme         393.9           15
```

I'm on youtube trying to find a video that will help me out.

Cant code.

Have been trying the Vlookup function...still haven't figured it out

Hope to get this sorted.